Alternative to dismiss in SwiftUI
I am having problems with dismiss environment variable in SwiftUI.
@Environment(\.dismiss) private var dismiss

Under certain conditions, the view body keeps getting recomputed and thereby calling all the functions invoked in .task modifier. Logging changes via Self._printChanges() shows that _dismiss changed. This is most likely an iOS bug has been reported on Apple developer forums by other users as well.
I want to avoid using dismiss therefore and want to know if there is an alternative to dismissing a view modally in SwiftUI.

It depends on how you present the view. If you are using a sheet modifier, you can pass in a binding and change its value. This might be useful: SwiftUI dismiss modal
